# Combine two onEdit functions, each of them working for its own sheets using its own data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two codes. Each of them gives me three drop-down lists depending on each other and works for different sheets. Each code uses its separate list of data.

How can I combine these two scripts, each of them working for 2 different pages? (in total there are 4 pages with three drop down lists)

First function:

```
var mainWsName1 = "PERSONELextra";   
var mainWsName2 = "ISKUR";                                                    
var optionsWsName = "Lists";   

var firstLevelColumn = 12;                               
var secondLevelColumn = 13;                              
var thirdLevelColumn = 14; 

var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);                                

   function onEdit(e){   

  var activeCell = e.range;                               
  var val = activeCell.getValue();                                
  var r = activeCell.getRow();                                
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();                             
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  // compare the edited sheet name against multiple allowed sheet anmes with ||                               
  if(wsName == mainWsName1 || wsName == mainWsName2 && r > 4){
    if(c == firstLevelColumn){                               
      applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r, wsName);                               
    } else if(c == secondLevelColumn){                               
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName);                              
    }  
  }                             
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r,wsName){
  //  obtain the sheet name dynamically from the onEdit() function  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
  } else {                                
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
    var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] == val });  // <--- Modified        
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });                              
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);                               
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);                                
  }                               
}                               

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName){   
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
} else {
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] == val });  // <--- Modified
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);  // <--- Modified
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(list)  // <--- Modified
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

And here is the second function for the other two sheets (and another data sheet):

```
var mainWsName1 = "GİDER";                                                       
var optionsWsName = "Lists2";   

var firstLevelColumn = 13;                               
var secondLevelColumn = 14;                              
var thirdLevelColumn = 15; 

var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);                                

function onEdit(e){                             
  var activeCell = e.range;                               
  var val = activeCell.getValue();                                
  var r = activeCell.getRow();                                
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();                             
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  // compare the edited sheet name against multiple allowed sheet anmes with ||                               
  if(wsName == mainWsName1 || wsName == mainWsName2 && r > 4){
    if(c == firstLevelColumn){                               
      applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r, wsName);                               
    } else if(c == secondLevelColumn){                               
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName);                              
    }  
  }                             
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r,wsName){
  //  obtain the sheet name dynamically from the onEdit() function  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
  } else {                                
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
    var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] == val });  // <--- Modified        
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });                              
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);                               
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);                                
  }                               
}                               

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName){   
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
} else {
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] == val });  // <--- Modified
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);  // <--- Modified
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(list)  // <--- Modified
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Rename the two `onEdit` functions to `onEdit1` and `onEdit2`. These names are up to you, but you can't have two `onEdit` functions.
- Put all the global variables you have outside of the `onEdit1` and `onEdit2` functions inside each function.
- You don't need to redefine the helper functions multiple times but you need them only once and they will work for both `onEdit1` and `onEdit2`.
- Finally, create an `onEdit` that will execute both `onEdit1` and `onEdit2`.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  onEdit1(e);
  onEdit2(e);
 }

 function onEdit1(e){   
  var mainWsName1 = "A1";   
  var mainWsName2 = "A2";                                                    
  var optionsWsName = "listforA";   
  var firstLevelColumn = 12;                               
  var secondLevelColumn = 13;                              
  var thirdLevelColumn = 14; 
  var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);           

  var activeCell = e.range;                               
  var val = activeCell.getValue();                                
  var r = activeCell.getRow();                                
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();                             
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  // compare the edited sheet name against multiple allowed sheet anmes with ||                               
  if(wsName == mainWsName1 || wsName == mainWsName2 && r > 4){
    if(c == firstLevelColumn){                               
      applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r, wsName,secondLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions)                               
    } else if(c == secondLevelColumn){                               
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName,firstLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions)                              
    }  
  }                             
} 
                          
function onEdit2(e){     
  var mainWsName1 = "B1";
  var mainWsName2 = "B2";                                                        
  var optionsWsName = "listforB";   
  var firstLevelColumn = 13;                               
  var secondLevelColumn = 14;                              
  var thirdLevelColumn = 15; 
  var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName);      
  var activeCell = e.range;                               
  var val = activeCell.getValue();                                
  var r = activeCell.getRow();                                
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();                             
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  // compare the edited sheet name against multiple allowed sheet anmes with ||                               
  if(wsName == mainWsName1 || wsName == mainWsName2 && r > 4){
    if(c == firstLevelColumn){                               
      applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r, wsName,secondLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions);                               
    } else if(c == secondLevelColumn){                               
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName,firstLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions);                              
    }  
  }                             
} 

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r,wsName,secondLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions){
  //  obtain the sheet name dynamically from the onEdit() function  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
  } else {                                
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearContent();                               
    ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                               
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();                                
    ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();                                
    var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] == val });  // <--- Modified        
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });                              
    var cell = ws.getRange(r, secondLevelColumn);                               
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);                                
  }                               
}                               

function applySecondLevelValidation(val,r, wsName,firstLevelColumn,thirdLevelColumn,wsOptions){   
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsName);                            
  if(val == ""){                             
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
} else {
ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
var filteredOptions = wsOptions.getDataRange().getValues().filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] == val });  // <--- Modified
var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
var cell = ws.getRange(r, thirdLevelColumn);  // <--- Modified
applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(list)  // <--- Modified
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I couldn't make it work. First, I copied your code, it didn't work. Than I made all the changes by myself according to your instructions, there was no result. And then I tried to **put all the global variables I have outside of the onEdit1 function inside** as you said, but for only one function. And it didn't worked. I mean if I put global variables above the row  **function onEdit1(e){ **, than the function works (the single function, as it worked before). If these variables are under the row **function onEdit1(e){ **, than it doesn't work...

Comment: @Sanli I am sorry the solution didn't work. Could you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here is the link for editable sheet: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vVu1K7HmDkT67U6td3UF5Raf4mC5whWwopYO1MFsLv8/edit?usp=sharing). I've added both functions, the first one was working correctly before I added the second one)

Comment: @Sanli I updated my code and it works for me in the sheet you shared with me. Make sure when you transfer the code to your original sheet to change the sheet names and references carefully. To test the code in the sheet you shared with me, delete the codes from both scripts you have and paste the one in my solution.